# dealing with money and Big Decimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal, money-format

I am trying to write a program that stores money in a variable,
so I am using Bigdecimal type as it was advised by other memebers here..
 But what I am trying to do is this.. user can type in what ever way he wants means to say, he can type

```
 24
 or
 24.0
 or
 24.00
```

so as you can see that I am giving the user flexibility to type at his own convenience. But in the end the variable will be stored in an array (BigDecimal array) so when it stores I want to store with and only 2decimal places. Why I say that is if the user types in 24 I want to store 24.00 NOT 24 or 24.0 JUST 24.00 or if he enters 24.00 then that will be stored with out any modification done to it.. how to do this..
 Sample code provided below.

```
    BigDecimal bala;
    BigDecimal balintake;
    static BigDecimal[] bal= new BigDecimal[20];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    balintake = sc.nextBigDecimal();

     bala.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
     bal[0] = bala;
```

But this is not working as according to my requirements.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you are more concerned about what gets displayed than what gets stored, right? If so, you can control the precision during printing (based on where you are printing, i.e on console or in some UI)

Comment: @Vikdor hey man, i have to do searching as well on the bigdecimal array later on, in a different method.. so in that also i need to do the same give the user flexibilty and then convert to 2decimal places as that is what stored in the search. So in general i am trying to make it standardized..

Comment: Could you not simply store your values as integers, e.g. `2400`? Then you just need to worry about the conversion to/from this integer value from the possible decimal representations supplied by the user.

Comment: You can go with DecimalFormat for this requirement ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that BigDecimal objects are immutable. So, when you do

```
balintake.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

you should assign it to back to a variable, like

```
balintake = balintake.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

Answer (score 1):

[java.math.BigDecimal.setScale(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int%29) returns a **new** BigDecimal instead of mutating the original one.

> Note that since BigDecimal objects are immutable, calls of this
>   method do not result in the original object being modified, contrary
>   to the usual convention of having methods named setX mutate field X.
>   Instead, setScale returns an object with the proper scale; the
>   returned object may or may not be newly allocated.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you never initialized the variable "bala"

So you set "balintake" to be the Scanner's next big decimal. 
The "setScale" method doesn't change the BigDecimal itself since BigDecimals are immutable, it returns a new BigDecimal with the scale set.

I believe this is what you want:

```
BigDecimal balintake;
BigDecimal[] bal= new BigDecimal[20];
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
balintake = sc.nextBigDecimal();

balintake = balintake.setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
bal[0] = balintake;
```